# Force customers to manually enter shipping address

Tags: paypal

I get at least five customers a week asking me to rectify their incorrect shipping address (and I have to deal with several non-receipt disputes per month).

I don't use any kind of shopping cart software to handle addresses on my site - it all happens over at PayPal.

What's happening is this: customers are directed to PayPal's checkout page and WITHOUT REALIZING they assign an old shipping address (which PayPal has kept on file since their last purchase).

Is there a way to force the customer to MANUALLY enter their shipping address when they arrive at PayPal's checkout?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think you can **force** your customers to do anything.

Comment: No such option. You can require that they select/provide a shipping address, but not force them to re-enter one. Which is a Very Good Thing for your conversion rates, even if some of your customers screw it up.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected this may be the case.Conversion rates aside, IF I did want to require the customer to input their shipping details manually, this is still possible right? Only, I'd have to collect that information on my website and pass it through to PayPal?